# Set and verify SSL/TLS version used in Python MySQL connection

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, mysql-connector-python

- How can I tell the Python MySQL connector which SSL/TLS protocol to use? Either specific (e.g. TLS1.2) or minimum.
- How can I check which protocol is used on an established connection?

I've got an app that uses `mysql-connector-python` (8.0.18). I connect something like this:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='x', password='y', host='localhost', database='xyz')
```

Usually this gives me no trouble, but recently on a web hosting providers server it stopped working. The error I'm now getting is along the lines of:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

And (connecting through Flask-SQLAlchemy setup):

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: SSL connection error: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

What I can confirm is that if I instead do `ssl_disabled=True`, as below, it connects properly (but without SSL/TLS I assume):

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='x', password='y', host='localhost', database='xyz', ssl_disabled=True)
```

I cannot alter the providers server, but they say that if I specify a specific version to use, for example TLS1.2, then it should connect properly. They also mention using the [`ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3), however that is part of the SSLContext setup which I'm unsure how to apply to my connection.

I see that on their MySQL instance (which I cannot edit) they have no value set for:

- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tls_version'`
- `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'`
- `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_version'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my recent understanding and help from [Andreas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394166/2732991) I ended up with the following connect:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='u', password='p', host='localhost', database='db', ssl_ca='', ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
```

Looking at the source, apparently all `kwargs` provided that are also in [`mysql.connector.constants.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/b034f25ec8037f5d60015bf2ed4ee278ec12fd17/lib/mysql/connector/constants.py#L39) are accepted. This includes several that are not included in [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html), like `ssl_version` and `ssl_cipher`. This mapping from `kwargs` to the connection appears to happen in [`MySQLConnectionAbstract.connect`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/b034f25ec8037f5d60015bf2ed4ee278ec12fd17/lib/mysql/connector/abstracts.py#L333). Note that setting `ssl_version` might require some other kwargs as well. I needed to provide `ssl_ca` along with it (might vary depending on what your MySQL instance has in `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%'`).

With that in mind, I've got the following MVCE code:

```
import mysql.connector
import ssl

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='u', password='p', host='localhost', database='db', ssl_ca='', ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT 1")

for (number,) in cursor:
    print('Number:', number)
print('SSL active:', cnx._ssl_active)
print('Connection SSL version:', cnx._ssl.get("version"))
print("Socket SSL version:", cnx._socket.sock.ssl_version)

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Which for me outputs:

```
Number: 1
SSL active: True
Connection SSL version: _SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
Socket SSL version: _SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
```

If I do the same connection without specifying `ssl_version` I get:

```
Number: 1
SSL active: True
Connection SSL version: None
Socket SSL version: _SSLMethod.PROTOCOL_TLS
```

If you replace `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` with `ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23` it should at least attempt a different protocol, but might fail if there are issues (e.g. unsupported).

Answer (score 2):

According to the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-python/en/news-8-0-18.html), there is now a "tls-versions" option in 8.0.18 that allows your to specify the TLS version.

The connections should look something like this.

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='x', password='y', host='localhost', database='xyz', tls-versions='tls1.2')
```

I have not verfied the actual value of tls-versions so you may need to try a couple different values.

Comment: mysql documentation does not necessarily match 1:1 with python code. `-` is not a valid character for a keyword argument and what you've provided is invalid Python syntax.

Comment: this is the correct syntax `cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='x', password='y', host='localhost', database='xyz', tls_versions=['TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2'])`

Answer (score 2):

In the source code I see a reference to `ssl_options.get('version', None)`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/b034f25ec8037f5d60015bf2ed4ee278ec12fd17/lib/mysql/connector/connection.py#L197

This variable is referenced in `switch_to_ssl` and is passed to [`ssl.wrap_socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket). The value here can be any of the `PROTOCOL_*` constants defined in the `ssl` module - https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS

The `_do_auth` method is called from `_open_connection`, which again is called from the `connect` method, and the value of `ssl_options` is `self._ssl`: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/b034f25ec8037f5d60015bf2ed4ee278ec12fd17/lib/mysql/connector/connection.py#L286-L288

There doesn't seem to be a way to control `connection._ssl` from the `connect` function, so we'll have to construct the object ourselves:

```py
import ssl
try:
    from mysql.connector.connection_cext import CMySQLConnection as MySQLConnection
except ImportError:
    from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection

connection = MySQLConnection()
connection._ssl['version'] = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
connection.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', database='example')
```

The above code was tested against a mysql Docker container started like this:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true -e MYSQL_DATABASE=example -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 mysql
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. From this digging I found an approach that suited me, so I won't mark it as accepted answer it since I ended up using a slightly different method, but it provided with me with invaluable input and deserves the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experiments, the order of the import is the issue.
The following works:

```
import mysql.connector
import ssl
```

The following doesn't work:

```
import ssl
import mysql.connector
```

no matter if you set the `ssl_ca='', ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` or not.

Also you get the same if you `import requests` instead of `import ssl`.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at our current configuration：

test env:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.27                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1                |
| version                 | 5.7.27                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

prodcut env:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name                    | Value                 |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| innodb_polar_restore_old_version | OFF                   |
| innodb_version                   | 8.0.13                |
| protocol_version                 | 10                    |
| rds_audit_log_version            | MYSQL_V1              |
| rds_version                      | 13                    |
| slave_type_conversions           |                       |
| tls_version                      | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 |
| version                          | 8.0.13                |
| version_comment                  | Source distribution   |
| version_compile_machine          | x86_64                |
| version_compile_os               | Linux                 |
| version_compile_zlib             | 1.2.11                |
+----------------------------------+-----------------------+
12 rows in set (0.98 sec)
```

The previous version used is 8.0.16 and the release is correct. After the automatic update to 8.0.19, the test environment begins to appear the above error，But the production environment is not wrong。

So I added ssl_disabled = True according to the above operation

```
ssl_disabled=True
```

But I don’t know how it will affect those things.

I think this is because the 8.0.19 version uses TLSv1.2 by default, so it caused an error in my test environment.But I didn't find relevant documentation